# How to get specific property of gmail emails when requesting a list?

Tags: c#, email, gmail-api

I work with Gmail API, I found how to get a list of message ids and, in a loop, how to get specific properties of those emails separately.
Problem is to make **request for each email is very slow**, mainly when my client have hundreds of mails ordered in hundreds labels...

I've tried to find a method to get one specific property at the first request, when I use `UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest`, but unsuccessfully...
For information, the property I want to get is "**Message-ID**" (not the id given by Google).

I did it once with Exchange Web Service, that why I'm looking to do it with Gmail API, if possible.

Thanks for answers in advance.

*PS: Excuse my English, which is not my native language.*

Answer (score 0):

When you make your request to the API you can send an optional parameter called [fields](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/query-parameters) it will allow you to return a partial response and just the fields that you are intrested in

[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/performance#partial)

> https://www.googleapis.com/demo/v1?key=YOUR-API-KEY&fields=kind,items(title,characteristics/length)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information. I tried this :
`UsersResource.MessagesResource.ListRequest listRequest = accountGmailService.Users.Messages.List("me");
listRequest.Fields = "messages(id,payload/headers)";
IList<Message> messageList = listRequest.Execute().Messages;`

It does't seem to work. Payload is null. :(